# Windows and renaming folders, the 'con' issue

Tags: windows, directory

Why in Windows, can't you name a folder 'con'?

Whenever I try to name a folder as "con" (without the quotes) it defaults to its original name.

Why does it do this?

Comment: Emin, I am sorry. But why you should ask a question for which the info is already available on the net?

Comment: I agree; it was easy to find http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071022041555AAkZGwZ (I hate Yahoo! Answers too, but it actually provided a valid answer) in a Google search for "windows rename folder to con."

Comment: If that were the test for whether a question should be asked we would be closing 99% of them.  The point is to build up tis site as an all-in-one resource.

Comment: Not programming related in any way... should be closed

Comment: I'm very lenient about what contitutes a valid question for SO, but it should at least have some kind of programming angle.  This doesn't, at all.  It's an OS question, relating to using a computer.

Comment: Anyone remembers the C:\con\con Win95 bug?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I realize I'm responding 6 years late, but this is absolutely related to programming - attempting to do the rename through code rather than a command results in the same problem, for the same reason.

Comment: If you were to remove each and every question on SO not related to programming, SO would not exists. PLUS just because I do not provide a code for it does not mean I did not come accross to the problem out of the subject. If you cannot guess even that, then I can't help you guys..

Comment: There is a great answer for the question 'why'. MS-DOS 2.0 to maintain backwards compatibility with applications designed for MS-DOS 1.0, which had no concept of directories. And MS-DOS 1.0 inherited that from operating system called CP/M (1973) https://bitquabit.com/post/zombie-operating-systems-and-aspnet-mvc/

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Back in the MS-DOS days, "con" had a special meaning. It referred to the console, and allowed you to treat it like any other file. For example, you might create a new text file by typing `copy con new.txt`. Then you could enter your text and hit `^Z` when finished.

The thing is, you can still do that. Therefore, as far as the file system is concerned there is already an object out there named `con`. There are [other reserved names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247) as well, but I see that while typing this those names have been provided already in other answers.

Comment: Ah; I had not known that.  Pretty cool.  =]

Comment: + 1 for answering the implied question as to "why" CON is reserved.

Comment: Whatever the reason might be, microsoft should have hidden this from the user. can you imagine an old couple (who doesn't have a clue about DOS and the old times of computing) getting frustrated trying to rename their grandchildren's photo album to CON (or the other reserved ones) ??

Comment: @Emin, Well, you can't name a folder "friends/family" either, but at least that gives you an error message.  I think renaming to "con" (and others) shouldn't be silently ignored.

Comment: @strager you ment absolutely what I thought. I just cannot imagine my father trying to do that without an error message. He would probably come to me the next day saying the computer is broken :)

Comment: Updated to add a link to reserved names.

Answer (score 24):

> Do not use the following reserved device names for the name of a file:
>
> CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9

[Source: MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx)

Other names, such as drive names, cannot be used as well:

> CLOCK$, A:-Z:

[Source: Microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/74496/en-us)

Comment: using "CLOCK$" is not a problem - I tested it myself

Answer (score 15):

Actually you can rename the folder to `con`

use this in the command prompt and this creates a system folder named `con` on your C: Drive

```
md \\\\\.\\\C:\con
```

to remove this folder you need to use this in the command prompt

```
rd/s \\\\.\\\C:\con
```

And just for those that are wondering "so why would you?" - my name is CON and if I wish to use that as my folder I WILL so "bugger you MS"

Con "OzDing"

Comment: Windows 10: "The specified path is invalid"

Comment: I tested with:
del \\?\C:\My\Path\NUL   
and it works

Answer (score 2):

This dates back to MS-DOS.  Reading or writing to a file named "CON:" read/wrote from the console.  I imagine Windows is still supporting this for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score -2):

From [Microsoft TechNet](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/Windows2000Pro/reskit/part3/proch17.mspx):

> Several special file names are reserved by the system and cannot be used for files or folders:
>
> CON, AUX, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4,
>   LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, PRN, NUL

Comment: Your link brings me to a "Windows XP" page without your quote.