# How to use str_replace with array or shorten the regex and php instead of repeating three times?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following which replace all of å, ø, æ .... etc to just _.

```
$string = strtolower($string);
$regexp = '/( |å|ø|æ|Å|Ø|Æ|Ã¥|Ã¸|Ã¦|Ã…|Ã˜|Ã†)/iU';
$replace_char = '_';
$data = preg_replace($regexp, $replace_char, $string);
```

Now I want to change them to according to the followings.

Replace,

space to _

å, Å, Ã¥ and Ã… to a,

ø, Ø, Ã and Ã˜¸ to o,

æ, Æ, Ã¦ and Ã† to e.

Can I use str_replace with array to do it? If yes, how to?

Or do I have to repeat the same regex three times?

Could anyone tell me better way to write the code?

--EDIT--

Pleas **ignore the encoding** at the moment.
I am **NOT** asking advices about encoding now.

I asked the encoding problem here. [Norwegian characters problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989806/norwegian-characters-problem)

Comment: It seems that you’re a little confused with character encodings.

Comment: Though you're not asking advice about encoding, the question seems to rise from a problem with translating encoding A (e.g. utf-8) to encoding B (ascii)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) that you can pass a mapping:

```
$mapping = array(
    'å' => 'a', 'Å' => 'a', 'Ã¥' => 'a', 'Ã…' => 'a',
    'ø' => 'o', 'Ø' => 'o', 'Ã' => 'o', 'Ã˜' => 'o',
    'æ' => 'e', 'Æ' => 'e', 'Ã¦' => 'e', 'Ã†' => 'e'
);
$str = strtr($str, $mapping);
```

But you should rather fix your encoding issue before. Because then you could use transliteration with [`iconv`](http://php.net/iconv):

```
$str = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $str);
```

Comment: My development environment is XAMPP/Windows. It must be something to do with Windows. But I don't really know how to fix it.

Comment: Not sure if `iconv` is available on all installations and if it's not if it is a concern for OP, but thought I'd comment on that.

Comment: shin, maybe you should (1) look into your php.ini for encodings and (2) use utf-8-enabled editor.

Comment: @Michael Krelin: What do I need to check with phpinfo? I have Accept-Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 And iconv.input_encoding ISO-8859-1 ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding ISO-8859-1 ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding ISO-8859-1 ISO-8859-1
etc.

Comment: @shin: You need to know how your data actually encoded. The second one is just an example how to transliterate from UTF-8 to ISO 8859-1.

Answer (score 1):

Like Gumbo said, you have some troubles with encoding, but leaving this fix to you the general idea would be

```
$data=preg_replace('/[ åøæÅØÆ]/iu','_',mb_strtolower($string,'utf-8'));
```

Note the `mb_` variant of strtolower, in case you want to work with unicode.

**Edit**: And stakx's suggestion also makes sense, but it changes the logic.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution utilizing mappings is to use `str_replace`. I used a minimal set of your mappings for an example.  Each value of `$search` maps to the corresponding index in `$replace`.

```
$search = array(' ', 'å', 'ø', 'æ', 'Å', 'Ø','Æ','Ã¥');
$replace = array('_', 'a', 'o', 'e', 'a', 'o', 'e', 'a');
$string = str_replace($search, $replace, mb_strtolower($string, 'utf-8');
```