# How to merge 2 zip files together into 1 zip

Tags: c#, jar, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to make a custom launcher for Minecraft in C# but I have come across a bump.

I want to add something into it, Minecraft Forge, but the only way I could think of is to change the extension of `minecraft.jar` to `minecraft.zip`, extract the contents of the `Minecraft Forge.zip` and the `minecraft.zip` into the same folder and then zip that entire folder up into `minecraft.jar`.

However `minecraft.jar` has a file named `aux.class` so whenever my extract script (Made in java) tries to extract it, it simply says:

> Unable to find file G:\Programming\C#\Console\Forge Installer\Forge Installer\bin\Debug\Merge\aux.class.

The only other way I can think of is to merge `minecraft_forge.zip` into `minecraft.zip`, I have spent around 2 hours looking on Google (watch as someone sees it within a couple of minutes) but it always shows me results for "How to zip multiple files", "How to make a zip file in C#" etc.

So I have come here looking for my answer, sorry if this is a lot to read but I always see comments on here saying "You didn't give enough information for us to help you with".

EDIT: The question in case it wasn't clear is: How am I able to put the contents of `minecraft_forge.zip` into `minecraft.zip`?

Comment: You should show the code of your "extract script". It seems it is not reading the jar/zip file...

Comment: The .jar is working fine, the problem is that **aux** is an illegal name in windows so I can't move it anywhere outside of that zip.
If I take the `aux.class` out then it works without failing.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, if you cannot unzip the files due to OS limitations, you need to "skip" unzipping temporary files to zip them. Instead, only handle input & output streams, as suggested in the answers found here: [How can I add entries to an existing zip file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048669/how-can-i-add-entries-to-an-existing-zip-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, "aux" is a protected keyword within windows and it does not matter what the file suffix may be; windows won't let you use it.  Here are a couple of threads that discusses this in general.

[Ref 1: Windows reserved words.](https://superuser.com/questions/86999/unable-to-rename-a-folder-or-a-file-as-con)

[Ref 2: Windows reserved words.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448438/windows-and-renaming-folders-the-con-issue)

If you are typing in commands to perform the copy or unzip, there is a chance you can get this to work by using a path prefix of the following `\\.\` or `\\?\`.  When I tested this, it worked with either a single or double back-slash following the period or question mark. Such that the following work:

```
\\.\c:\paths\etc
\\.\\c:\paths\etc
\\?\c:\path\etc
\\?\\c:\path\etc
```

I used the following command to test this.  When trying to rename through windows explorer it gave a "The specified device name is invalid." error message.  From the command line it worked just fine. I should point out, that once you create these files, you will have to manually delete them using the same technique.  Windows Explorer reports that these text files which have a size of 0 bytes "is too large for the destination file system", ie... the recycle bin.
    rename "\.\c:\temp\New Text Document.txt" aux.txt
    del "\.\c:\temp\aux.txt"

As far as copying directly from zip or jar files, I tried this myself and it appeared to work.  I used [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) and opened the jars directly using the "open archive..." windows explorer context menu.  I then dragged-and-dropped the contents from forge.jar to the minecraft jar file.  Since it is the minecraft jar file with the offending file name the chance of needing to create a temporary file on the filesystem is reduced.  I did see someone mention that 7-zip may extract to a temporary file when copying between jars and zips. 
[7-zip reference on copying between archives](http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/ec73f124/)

I should point out that my copy of minecraft jar (minecraft_server.1.8.7.jar) did not contain a file named aux.class.  I also did not try to use the jar after the copy/merge.  Nor did I spend too much time trying to figure out how well it merged the two contents since it appears like there may be a conflict with `com\google\common\base\` since there are similar class name but with different `$` variable suffixes on them.

I hope these two possible suggestions could give you some room to work with to find a solution for your needs... if you're still looking.