# Github automatically deletes a file during clone

Tags: windows, git, github, github-for-windows, git-shell

I'm having trouble cloning one of my private repositories into my computer. Currently I've tried both using the application and the console and neither work.

Using the application: No errors are specifically shown, but upon the completion of the clone the diff shows I already deleted a file, con.py [image]

---

Upon attempting to clone using the **console** , I actually something i've never seen before:
[image]

It doesn't grab all of the objects...and then goes on to print out the entire file it deletes right afterwards which is weird.

I tried looking up solutions with no luck, moving the directory to a shorter path did nothing as most sites recommended. Please help!

Comment: Shot in the dark, but what happens if you rename the file?

Comment: you can't have a file named `con` in Windows. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448438/windows-and-renaming-folders-the-con-issue

Comment: Well that solved my problem, thanks @kaman if you post an answer i'll accept it

Comment: Actually first comment provided you a valid solution so PeeHaa should get credit for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`con` is a reserved name in windows so it can't exist on a windows machine.

One thing you can do is to **change the name of your file** and that should do the trick.