# AccessDeniedException X509Certificates C#

Tags: c#, digital-signature

I'm trying to work with certificate throght .net library, in particular X509Certificates.

But AccessDeniedException falls during work.

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("C:\\AirAstana\\Project\\con\\AUTH_RSA_7525b02122ff0bd4561712317510a376b8c7cd1b.p12", "pass", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable); 
byte[] certData = certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, "pass"); 

Convert.ToBase64String(certData)
```

What is wrong?

Following error falls

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>CERTIFICATE_NOT_VALID</faultstring>
<detail>
<ns2:AccessDeniedException xmlns:ns2="http://ru.uss.esf/">
<description>CERTIFICATE_NOT_VALID</description>
</ns2:AccessDeniedException></detail>
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Maybe because the _first_ error seems to be `CERTIFICATE_NOT_VALID`?

Comment: Are you running your IDE as an administrator?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the path is not valid:

> C:\AirAstana\Project\**con**\AUTH.....

`CON` is a reserved word in Windows you must try to change it.

Comment: @RalphWillgoss That is true; try it out by yourself.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448438/windows-and-renaming-folders-the-con-issue for evidence