# File.Exists returning True when should be False

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a program which requires the lookup of files in user defined directories. If the files don't exist, it must continue to use it's own resources. The problem is, even though some files don't exist, the function File.Exists returns true for them.

Here is an image of the error:

[image: Error]

Here is the code that looks for the file and produces the error:

```
string[] vmtLines = null;
if (File.Exists(vmtFile))
{
    try { vmtLines = File.ReadAllLines(vmtFile); }
    catch (Exception e) { Debug.Log(vmtFile + " Exists: " + File.Exists(vmtFile) + ", " + e.Message); }
}
```

Comment: Where is vmtFile declared?

Comment: If it says it exists, there's a high probability that the framework isn't broken.  Have you refreshed, re-sorted, enabled showing hidden and system files etc?

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed it, supposedly. Thanks for letting me know, and also is it still broken now?

Comment: "Invalid handle to path" so its more likely a read failure, do you have permissions?

Comment: Yes show us the exception type please. If @AlexK. is correct then you will see `SecurityException` or `UnauthorizedAccessException`. If you are right and the file doesn't exist then you will see `FileNotFoundException`. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Charles for the reply, I just tried refreshing the folder, nothing new. I checked through [cmd](http://i.imgur.com/Gp0Rgu2.png) for hidden or system files, nothing

Comment: Ok, I will check what type the error is, but I don't think it's a SecurityException or the other. Mainly because it was able to read other files from the same directory. Thanks for the input, I'll be right back with results.

Comment: So I [printed](http://i.imgur.com/hvkZOft.png) the exception type with the error, and the output was System.IO.IOException. Also @Programmer, vmtFile is a string defined from earlier in the code. It is printed with the error in the catch block.

Comment: instead of doing `e.Message` do `e.ToString()` and have that logged instead. It will contain extra information that will be helpful to us

Comment: Thanks @ScottChamberlain, I will do that now. LarsTech I replace all back slashes with forward slashes in file operations.

Comment: @LarsTech That's likely the problem. I think that the problem is how he constructed the file name. The file name is stored in `vmtFile` but he doesn't want to post the code where he initialized `vmtFile` variable.

Comment: @Programmer but the error prints vmtFile, you can see it in the image, what does it matter how it was constructed. The construction of the string is quite complicated and spans multiple functions, it would be very tedious to put it up.

Comment: @LarsTech I have already loaded files using forward slashes in the same block of code.

Comment: @LarsTech I just noticed you wrote that they are not legal in the file name. I thought you meant in splitting directories. The forward slashes are not part of the name of the file. The file that it should be checking if it exists is con.vmt within the directory C:\Users\oxter\Documents\csgo\models\props_fortifications

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I tried as you suggested and it still only shows System.IO.IOException

Comment: @LarsTech Windows paths should accept either one, see [Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.altdirectoryseparatorchar(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem is not in C#, Unity, or my programming. It seems there's a problem with files that are called con. I was testing out in the cmd to see if I could open the file con.vmt with notepad, here's what happened:

[image: Con]

Then I tried to see if the same thing happens with other files in the same directory:

[image: Random File]

It opened just fine. Then I tried to see if it were just 3 letter file names which was the problem by opening a file with the name com:

[image: Com]

It didn't have some weird problem, then I tried to see if it was something with the extension vmt and the file name con:

[image: ABC]

It had the same problem. I tried the same thing in the parent directory, and the same problem occurred with the file name con. So I assume this happens anywhere.

Thank you @Programmer, @CharlesMager, @AlexK, @Quantic, @ScottChamberlain, and @LarsTech for trying to help. This was one strange problem

Comment: See [Windows and renaming folders, the 'con' issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/448438/719186)

Comment: @LarsTech Wow! I'm so glad this problem didn't last longer than it could have. Thanks for the reference and help :)