# Cannot create a file with special name under windows7 ?!?!

Tags: c#, windows-7, filenames

Filename: CON.DE.csv
Error message (translated from German):
Filestream does not open Win32 devices....

I tried creating this file with C# and directly in a dos window.
Similar filenames like CON1.DE.csv are working.

Comment: First search result "windows filename con": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448438/windows-and-renaming-folders-the-con-issue

Comment: [What’s the deal with those reserved filenames like NUL and CON?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031022-00/?p=42073)

Comment: Next time, do a bit more research before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is another holdover from the old MSDOS days where special file names were used to signify special devices, like COM1, COM2, etc.. CON is one of them.

Related answer: [Windows and renaming folders, the 'con' issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448438/windows-and-renaming-folders-the-con-issue)