# Cannot delete aux file

Tags: windows

[image]

I was working on a React project and was creating a higher order element when I named the file Aux.js.  Now I cannot delete it or change its name.  Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This problem is the same as the `CON` issue on Windows, see [Windows and renaming folders, the 'con' issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448438/windows-and-renaming-folders-the-con-issue)

Long story short: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx indicates that `AUX` is also a *reserved word* within Windows (same as `CON` is) and therefore resides within the *Win32 Device Namespace* - as opposed to the *Win32 File Namespace* where normal files reside.

**Fixing the issue**

You cannot use the file name `Aux.js` on Windows, use e.g. `Auxx.js`.

**Removing the file**

You can delete the *device file* by explicitly addressing the device namespace via the prefix `\\.\`. If the file resides within, for example, `C:\temp\Aux.js`, then the following command will delete it:

```
del \\.\C:\temp\Aux.js
```

HTH

Comment: It worked. I was unable to delete specific file but deleting folder worked.

Comment: This also works with folders, just use `rmdir` instead.